# Using a Model with ChartKick (Rails5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to use the Timeline Graph from Google Graphs (Ala [ChartKick Gem](https://www.chartkick.com/)

It seems to be want an Array of data such as

```
<%= timeline [
  ["Washington", "1789-04-29", "1797-03-03"],
  ["Adams", "1797-03-03", "1801-03-03"],
  ["Jefferson", "1801-03-03", "1809-03-03"]
] %>
```

I'm a bit confused on how I could get it to fetch from a Model's data? In this case I would like the `Proposal` and the `start_date` and `completion_date` fields.
Both are stored in typical timestamps.

I tried iterating through an `each` but I get an error on 
`Error Loading Chart: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined`

I believe I will need to make a function within the controller but I'm not sure how to get return the data in the proper format, or how to even reference the controller.

Comment: Try to make an array as give in  `Chartkick Gem`

Comment: Hey @DNorthrup you just need this https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime to format your timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, do (I don't know your model name)

1) If you are saving DateTime object in your db

```
@array = Model.all.map{|a| [a.proposal, a.start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), a.completion_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]}
```

2) If you are saving integer timestamp

```
@array = Model.all.map{|a| [a.proposal, DateTime.strptime(a.start_date.to_s,'%s').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), DateTime.strptime(a.completion_date.to_s,'%s').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')]}
```

and in your view, do

```
<%= timeline @array %>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sajin - I actually managed to get it working with something similar, but I really like the way you output the information. I will try it tonight.